# Is OnItemSelectedListener.onNothingSelected called at all?

Tags: android, android-listview, listener

`OnItemSelectedListener` needs two methods to be implemented: `onItemSelected` and `onNothingSelected`. I was curious and tried doing some actions in the `onNothingSelected` method. However, I have not been able to trigger this event.

Is it actually called?

Answer (score 0):

The method `onNothingSelected` is called when the "selection disappears from this view."

Here are the Docs on the the [OnItemSelectedListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener.html).

Comment: It's not clear to me what the description in the documentation means. I expected this callback would be called if the user taps outside of the spinner dropdown to dismiss it without making a selection ... but like the OP, I haven't found any situation where the callback is called.

Comment: This answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16439463/why-is-onnothingselected-method-needed-in-spinner-listener/19940013#19940013 explains it pretty well @arlomedia